# Nginx configuration doesn't work properly on Tomcat

Tags: nginx, tomcat, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

Hi I am facing issue when configuring nginx as proxy server to redirect request to my tomcat server. I have 3 tomcat server running on different machine & different port like this

```
192.168.51.115:8115
192.168.51.120:8120
192.168.51.130:8130
```

Now I want to config nginx to pass request to my three server sequentially like this

```
www.example.com/app1
www.example.com/app2
www.example.com/app3
```

Real IP: 123.123.123.123

This is my configuration under - site-enabled

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location /app1 {
             proxy_pass "http://192.168.51.115:8115";
        }

        location /app2 {
                proxy_pass "http://192.168.51.120:8120";
        }

        location /app3 {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.51.130:8130;
        }
}
```

Note: When i put location directive placing just `/` then it works but doesn't work on `/*` like app1,app2 or app3

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using ^~ as modifier in your location block ?

like

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location ^~ /app1 {
             proxy_pass "http://192.168.51.115:8115";
        }

        location ^~ /app2 {
                proxy_pass "http://192.168.51.120:8120";
        }
        location ^~ /app3 {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.51.130:8130;
        }
}
```